# I can't get tomcat/jax-rs and maven to work in the same project on the same IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, jax-rs

Here's my problem. I need to make a restful web service that uses maven. I've tried making this work on Eclipse, Netbeans, and Intellij. But on all three I can either make it a maven project, or a rest service project. Since every tutorial online starts by creating either/or I have no idea what particular (pre-packaged) parts of the project structure are actually needed for either to work. Is there some simple way of merging the two functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

Create new maven project:

File > New > Project > Maven

Edit the pom.xml and add the needed dependencies (for REST, etc.)
This is all you need to work with RESTful services.

You can add REST Web Services support with:

Right-click on the project (project tool window on left) > Add Framework Support > Java EE > RESTful Web Service

The problem is that "RESTful Web Service" framework will want either to create or to use a library with REST-related dependencies (jars). Maven, on other hand has its own dependency mechanism (.m2 repo, etc.) . And btw, I don't think using  "REST Web Services support" does much more than setting up all the needed relevant libraries. I personally use only maven-type project for my REST projects.